# 2014 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2014 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://math.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: @Irr please do not make minimal, non-essential edits to old posts. The particular one, at least in my opinion, is even incorrect. There is no reason to typeset 2014 as mathematics.

Comment: I was quite surprised when I saw this on the front page of meta. Only after quid's comment I realized that the post has 2014 rather than 2017 in the title.